# How do I terminate the program in Java?

Tags: java

This is my code. The program won't give me the last print line "Thank you for using the Basic user Interface program."

```
public class nameClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input;
    String name;
    int age;
    double mileage;

    displayApplicationInformation();
    displayDivider("Start Program");
    TerminateApplication();

    // process name
    displayDivider("Get Name");
    name = getInput("name");
    System.out.println("Your name is: " + name);

    // Process age
    displayDivider("Get Age");
    input = getInput("Your age");
    age = Integer.parseInt(input);
    System.out.println("Your age is: " + age);

    // Process Mileage
    displayDivider("Get Mileage");
    input = getInput("Your MPG");
    mileage = Double.parseDouble(input);
    System.out.println("Your car MPG is: " + mileage);

  }// end of main

  public static void displayApplicationInformation()

  {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Basic User Interface Program");

  }// end of displayApplicaionInformation

  public static void displayDivider(String outputTitle) {

    System.out.println("*********" + outputTitle + "********");

  }// end of displayDvider

  public static String getInput(String inputType)

  {
    String input = "";
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the " + inputType);

    return input;

  }

  public static void TerminateApplication()

  {
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the Basic User Interface program");
    return;
  }

}// end of MainClass
```

Comment: You're not calling `TerminateApplication()` at the end of `main()`...

Comment: @arooba As `durron597` put below

Comment: You're doing it on the 9th line of `main()` - move this call to the end...

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Can you show us what does display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually call the method `TerminateApplication`;

```
System.out.println("Your car MPG is: " + mileage);

TerminateApplication();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, call `TerminateApplication`.
You are doing it on the 9th line of `main()`.
Here, check this out:

```
displayDivider("Get Mileage");
input = getInput("Your MPG");
mileage = Double.parseDouble(input);
System.out.println("Your car MPG is: " + mileage);
//add this...
TerminateApplication();
```

Hope this helps!